# C++ style: operator overload, pass by <flavor>

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I received the following comments from a recent code review:

> Avoid the use of operator overloading wherever possible: if using
>   std::string use .append() and .assign() instead of + and = for clarity
>
> Avoid passing by value or reference, use [C style] pointers instead

This is not my first run in with this sort of nonsense from this particular reviewer.

As in Animal Farm, some are more equal than others. How to let the boss know his pet provides no value doing peer reviews?

Citing chapter and verse from best practices are part of that answer, but I need more than just technical reasons (with out resorting to ad hominem attacks, satisfying as that might be). Advice appreciated.

Comment: " if using std::string use .append() and .assign() instead of + and = **for clarity**" ...That's so messed up... accept our sympathy

Comment: There's a massive shortage of good C++ programmers in the world. You could work somewhere that's less annoying?

Comment: It sounds like your peer reviewer comes from a java background and was taught to hate operator overloading.

Comment: All of these are advised by the *older* Google C++ Style Guide.  It is a document based in C++03 where it tells you to then program in the intersection of Java and C coding practices.  Not surprisingly, a good chunk of it was bad advice.  The [current Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html) is better.  It is still very conservative, which may make sense at a large organization.  Passing by pointer is worse than value, but there are solid arguments why by-pointer is better than by non-const reference (not unassailable, but worth considering).

Comment: Would this be more on topic on workplace.stackexchange.com?  It seems like the main point of the question is more about navigating office politics than about the technical contents of the reviews.

Comment: _Avoid passing by value or reference..._ Please accept my two weeks notice.

Answer (score 3):

There are actually objective reasons for both parts of the question, so I'm disagreeing with the close votes.

With respect to the first, `std::sort` (via `std::less`) assumes you have overloaded `operator<`. `std::ostream` assumes you overloaded a free function `operator<<(std::ostream&, Foo)`. `std::accumulate` assumes `operator+` etc. In short, the C++ standard itself assumes you will use operator overloading.

Of the 4 ways to pass a value (`T, T&, T&& and T*`), the last is the worst. It breaks move semantics, temporaries, increases the risk of memory leaks (ambiguous semantics) and again is incompatible with assumptions in the C++ standard. E.g. the copy constructor *cannot* take a `T*`.

Comment: I wouldn't call `T*` the worst way. It's all a question of semantics. If you want to pass an object to be modified by the function, pass it as `T&`. If you want the function to somehow work with the address of the object, pass it as `T*` to signal that is actually the address you are interested in.

Comment: "*In short, the C++ standard itself assumes you will use operator overloading.*" I assume a company that would endorse coding policies like the OP is describing would be avoiding the standard library like the plague. Just a hunch...

Answer (score 1):

Luckily for you, the entire draft standard is available in HTML format with direct links to every single section. It'll be trivial to show that `std::string::assign` and `std::string::operator=` are identical.

[21.3.1.6.3 string::assign](http://eel.is/c++draft/string::assign)

```
basic_string& assign(const basic_string& str);

     Effects: Equivalent to *this = str
```

[21.3.1.2/19 string.cons](http://eel.is/c++draft/string.cons#19)

```
basic_string& operator=(const basic_string& str);

     Effects: If *this and str are not the same object, modifies *this
```

If we implemented this to the letter, it would look like this:

```
basic_string& operator=(const value_type* __s) {return assign(__s);}
```

Where `value_type` is `Traits::char_type`, aka `char` for `std::string`.